# Nodejs editing image in imagemagick gm

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, imagemagick, aspect-ratio

I am trying to manipulate the original image after uploading it and then upload the result image.

I am trying to keep the aspect ratio of the original image in the new image which is resized and cropped

1. User will select interest point (x,y) in original image to start cropping from this point.
2. Crop the original image with the (x,y) points.
3. Resize the cropped image to have 512 height and keep the original image aspect ratio.

What is the best way to do this??

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
                        gm(cloudfronturl + permanentPath)
                            .crop(512, 512, 100, 100)
                            .resize(512, 512, '^')
                            .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                                newImage = permanentPath.substring(0, permanentPath.length - 4) + '_1024.jpg';
                                var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(cloudfront url + newImage);
                                stdout.pipe(writeStream);
                            });
```

The result image is a square with 512X512, but I want to keep the aspect ratio

Comment: Just a guess, but if you only want to resize the width, try `.resize('1024x')` and if you only want to change the height, try `.resize('x768`)` since the full syntax is probably `.resize('1024x768')`. I may be totally wrong.

Comment: I want to keep the aspect ratio of the cropped image

Comment: It will keep the aspect ratio, unless you add `!` immediately after the dimensions.

Comment: As you can see my code now, it's resulting a cropped image with dimensions 412X412

Comment: If you resize your image to 512x512, and then try and crop 512x512 starting at 100,100, you will presumably get a resulting image of 412x412. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to crop an image, the user will select x,y point to start cropping from there, then resize the result image with 512 height and keep the aspect ratio of the original image

Comment: So you need to crop first, then resize afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question

Comment: You need to know the top-left **AND** width and height to crop - does the user tell you the width and height? If not, put the x,y and 512 into your `crop()` command and you are all done. If the user does tell you the amount of the crop, or the bottom-right corner, then put those values in and `resize()` afterwards.

Comment: would you put this as an answer please. and you can read my question again just to be sure